# when does php foreach index increment?

Tags: php, foreach, kohana

```
$databaseObjects = Database::instance()->query('SELECT * FROM table');
foreach ($databaseObjects as $key => $value) {
    echo "(key: $key, value: $value)";
    if ($key + 1 < count($objects))
        $nextObject = $objects[$key + 1];
}
```

Given an array of database objects from Kohana, the above loop will skip all the odd keys. The reason for this is because accessing $objects[$key+1] increments $key. I don't understand the reason behind this. Since when did the array access operator increment the key?

Comment: It's not valid code: You're missing a `)` on the `if` line. Also, [`$key + 1` does not increment `$key`](http://codepad.org/jPWwm4zq). If you have tried to simplify the code, you've removed whatever the problem area is.

Answer (score 0):

`$objects[$key+1]` does not increment `$key`

Your code is weird - you set `$nextObject` but then never use it.

Remember: array keys are NOT always in order such as 0,1,2,3,4,5!

For instance, this array:

```
<?php
$arr = array(
    0 => "Zero",
    2 => "Two",
    5 => "Five"
);
?>
```

Would print out the following in your script:

```
(key: 0, value: Zero)(key: 2, value: Two)(key: 5, value: Five)
```

... and this array:

```
<?php
$arr = array(
    5 => "Five"
    2 => "Two",
    0 => "Zero",
);
?>
```

Would print out the following in your script:

```
(key: 5, value: Five)(key: 2, value: Two)(key: 0, value: Zero)
```

Answer (score 0):

`$objects[$key + 1];` does not increment the `$key`, `$key + 1` is not being assigned to `$key`. Moreover, even if $key was assigned $key + 1, this won't affect the $key variable in the next iteration since $key is local to the `foreach` and initialized every time the `foreach` iterate on the next element in the array.

However, since this is a `foreach` loop, the `$key` is nothing but the `index` (assuming this array is not an associative one). Therefore the `$key` will be incrementing starting from zero every time the loop iterate on an element.

Answer (score 0):

It appears I left out the important detail that I am iterating over Kohana database objects. They must have overwritten the foreach iterator in a fashion such that when I perform an array access within the foreach loop,

```
$nextObject = $objects[$key + 1];
```

it will affect the $key on the next iteration.